# PHP/MySql taking value from two different tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form

http://s12.postimg.org/5lylvp2h9/Untitled.png

table products

```
+----+---------------+
| id | product       |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | pencil        |
|  2 | Eraser        |
|  3 | Brush         |
|  4 | teddy bear    |
|  5 | panda         |
|  6 | kaleidoscope  |
+----+---------------+
```

table suppliers

```
+----+------------------+
| id | Suppliers        |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | Silberauto , Ltd.|
|  2 | MADATA , Ltd.    |
|  3 | Omnitel , Ltd.   |
|  4 | Profito IT Ltd.  |
|  5 | Arfix , Ltd.     |
+----+------------------+
```

table product_supplier

```
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| product_id | supplier_id | unit_cost |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
|          4 |           1 |     10.50 |
|          2 |           5 |     15.25 |
|          1 |           2 |     20.40 |
|          3 |           3 |     25.75 |
|          5 |           3 |     30.00 |
|          5 |           4 |     35.75 |
|          1 |           1 |     40.55 |
|          4 |           3 |     45.75 |
|          2 |           2 |     50.15 |
|          3 |           5 |     55.10 |
|          6 |           2 |     60.00 |
|          9 |           2 |     65.55 |
|          7 |           4 |     70.85 |
|          9 |           3 |     75.35 |
|          8 |           1 |     80.20 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

In my form select field I'm selecting an item(***pencil***) from table **products**. each item has an unique value which references to item id(table **products -> id**).

In radio select I'm selecting supplier(from table **suppliers**). radio button has **value**(in this example `MADATA,UAB`) and **name**(item id. in this example `7`)

In next field **price** I want to print `unit_cost` from table `product_suplier` where `product_id`(it is my `value` from select field.) is equal to `supplier` (from table `suppliers`).

in **kaina.php** my condition

```
SELECT unit_cost 
FROM product_supplier, suppliers
WHERE  product_id= :product_id AND suppliers.suppliers = :suppliers');

$stmt->execute(array('supplier' => $supplier,'product_id' => $product_id));

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['unit_cost']." LT ";
}
```

is bad. in this example it prints two values. how to change SELECT condition to take one value, not two(becouse there are two supliers who sells the same item).

my code:

**index.php**

```
<?
$username='root';
$password='pass';
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=univer', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'KLAIDA: ' . $e->getMessage();
}?>

<html>
  <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type= 'text/css' href='css/styles.css'>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type= 'text/css' href='css/bootstrap.css'>

 <script>

 function tiekejai(tiekejas){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tiekejai.php?q="+supplier,
        dataType: "html",             
        success: function(duomenys){                    
            $("#tiekejai").html(duomenys); 
        }
    });
};

function kaina(tiekejas,data){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "kaina.php?supplier="+supplier+"&product_id="+data,

        dataType: "html",             
        success: function(duomenys){                    
            $("#kaina").html(duomenys); 
        }
    });
};

</script>
</head>
<body>

<main id="content" role="content">
 <div id="forma">
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>  

<legend>Uzsakymo forma</legend>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic">Pasirinkite preke</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="selectas" name="selectas" class="input-xlarge" 
    onchange="tiekejai(this.value)">       
  <?php 

    $data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM products
                  INNER JOIN product_suplier
              ON products.id = product_suplier.product_id
              GROUP BY product');

    foreach($data as $row) {
        echo "<option value=".$row['product_id'].">".$row['product']."</option>";
    }
  ?> 
    </select>
  </div><!--.controls -->
</div><!--.control-group -->

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="radios">Pasirinkite tiekeja</label>
  <div class="controls" id="tiekejai">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="radios">kaina</label>
  <div class="controls">

<span class="uneditable-input" id="kaina">Prekes kaina</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Kiekis</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="max 40" class="input-xlarge" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for=""></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="" name="" class="btn btn-primary">Uzsakyti</button>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</main>
  <script>
  document.getElementById("selectas").selectedIndex = -1;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**tiekejai.php**

```
<?php

$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
if (!$con){
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}

mysql_select_db("univer", $con);

$sql="  SELECT * FROM suppliers
    INNER JOIN product_suppliers
    ON tiekejai.id = product_suppliers.product_id
    WHERE product_suppliers.product_id= '".$q ."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

       echo "<label class='radio'>";
       echo  "<input name='". $q ."' id=radios  
       value= '". $row['supplier'] ."'
        type='radio' onchange='kaina(this.value,this.name)'>";
       echo $row['supplier'];
       echo "</label>";
}
mysql_close($con);


?>
```

**kaina.php**

```
<?php
$supplier = $_GET['supplier'];
$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];

$username='root';
$password='pass';
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=univer', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('

       SELECT unit_cost 
       FROM product_supplier, suppliers
       WHERE  product_id= :product_id AND suppliers.suppliers = :suppliers');

$stmt->execute(array('supplier' => $supplier,'product_id' => $product_id));

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['unit_cost']." LT ";
    }  
  } 
 catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'KLAIDA: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Which one do you want?

Comment: that one which is on click

Answer (score 0):

I think going back and forth from Lithuanian to English is confusing both you and us. Can we do the whole thing in English for now? So that data set might look like this...

```
products
+----+---------------+
| id | product       |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | pencil        |
|  2 | Eraser        |
|  3 | Brush         |
|  4 | teddy bear    |
|  5 | panda         |
|  6 | kaleidoscope  |
+----+---------------+

suppliers
+----+------------------+
| id | Suppliers        |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | Silberauto , Ltd.|
|  2 | MADATA , Ltd.    |
|  3 | Omnitel , Ltd.   |
|  4 | Profito IT Ltd.  |
|  5 | Arfix , Ltd.     |
+----+------------------+

product_supplier
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| product_id | supplier_id | unit_cost |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
|          4 |           1 |     10.50 |
|          2 |           5 |     15.25 |
|          1 |           2 |     20.40 |
|          3 |           3 |     25.75 |
|          5 |           3 |     30.00 |
|          5 |           4 |     35.75 |
|          1 |           1 |     40.55 |
|          4 |           3 |     45.75 |
|          2 |           2 |     50.15 |
|          3 |           5 |     55.10 |
|          6 |           2 |     60.00 |
|          9 |           2 |     65.55 |
|          7 |           4 |     70.85 |
|          9 |           3 |     75.35 |
|          8 |           1 |     80.20 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Note: I got rid of the id column on the product_supplier table because it appears to serve no purpose.
Now, what's the problem?